# Multiple listings using range markers and PGF's \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, pgf-core

I've been trying to include multiple code snippets from a unique source file by using `listings`'s range markers (named lines) and PGF's `\foreach` macro:

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,8} {
  \lstinputlisting[linerange=P\x-FIN\ P\x]{programas.py}
}
```

It doesn't work: no code is inserted at all. When passing the range name explicitly to `\lstinputlisting` (without using `\foreach`'s counter), then the code is inserted correctly:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange=P1-FIN\ P1]{programas.py}
```

Minimum (non-)working example: 
https://gist.github.com/1371840

How could I make it work? Is it listing's or foreach's fault?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\lstinputlisting` doesn't seem to expand its arguments, so the `\x` is not replaced with the current number. You can work around this by using an `\edef` (an "expanded definition") to define a new macro that contains your `\lstinputlisting` line with expanded arguments, and then call that.

The lines

```
    \edef\dolisting{\noexpand\lstinputlisting[linerange=P\x-FIN\ P\x]{programas.py}}
    \dolisting
```

first define a new macro `\dolisting`, with everything except for the `\lstinputlisting` keyword expanded, and then call that new macro.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{programas.py}
# P\x
s = {78, 15, 91, 15}
print len(s)
# FIN P\x

# P2
d = {78: 15, 91: 15}
print len(d)
# FIN P2

# P3
n = (17, 3, 1993)
h = (14, 5, 2011)
print n < h
# FIN P3

# P4
x, y = ((27, 3), 9)
z, w = x
print y + w
# FIN P4

# P5
a = 'acabase'
b = set(a)
c = list(b)
c.sort()
print c[2]
# FIN P5

# P6
t = 'papagayo'
w = t.split('a')
print w[3]
# FIN P6

# P7
def f(a, b):
    return a + 2 * b

a = 5
b = 2
print f(b, a)
# FIN P7


# P8
def f(a):
    return x + a

def g(x):
    return x + a

x = 5
a = 7
print f(x) + g(x)
# FIN P8

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{courier}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\lstset{language=python}
\lstset{rangeprefix=\#\ }
\lstset{includerangemarker=false}

\begin{document}

  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8} {
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[b]{19.8em}
    \edef\dolisting{\noexpand\lstinputlisting[linerange=P\x-FIN\ P\x]{programas.py}}
    \dolisting
      \framebox[18em]{\rule[6ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
      \vspace{0.7em}
    \end{minipage}
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about ``\edef``. Thanks!